# How to compare a string with an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string

The task is to check for the presence of a word from an array in a string.

```py
str = 'Dear friends, the new model of organizational activity contributes to the preparation and implementation of the personnel training system.'

stop_words = [ 'training', 'moonshine']


if all(stop_words in str):
    print('Find stop word')
else:
    print('All goods, no stop words')
```

Here python says that he can't compare it. Tell me plese what are the solutions?

Comment: "he can't edit it" what ?

Comment: Sorry "compare"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following error

> `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list`

As you wan't search a `list` into a `str`, that has no sense, you can only search for a string into another string, but you have to do it for each string of your list

---

Regarding your string `no stop words`, I guess you want the following, you want **any** (not each) `word` from `stop_words` to be in `value`

```py
value = 'Dear friends, the new model of organizational activity contributes to the preparation and implementation of the personnel training system.'
stop_words = [ 'training', 'moonshine']

if any(word in value for word in stop_words):
    print('Find a stop word')
else:
    print('All goods, no stop words')
```